# In Rails using Postgres, how do you add an index on an array of UUIDs?

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5, uuid

I'm trying to add an index on an array of UUIDs in Rails using Postgres 9.6. This is my migration...

```
class AddProductIdsToApplications < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_column :applications, :product_ids, :uuid, array: true, default: [] 
    add_index :applications, :product_ids, using: 'gin'
  end
end
```

I'm getting this error...

```
>     PG::UndefinedObject: ERROR:  data type uuid[] has no default operator class for access method "gin"
>     HINT:  You must specify an operator class for the index or define a default operator class for the data type.
```

Is there a migration fix for this?

Comment: Have a look at https://coderwall.com/p/1b5eyq/index-for-uuid-array-data-type HTH